# Get keys from a dictionary that contains duplicate list values, then store their corresponding keys in a nested list

Tags: python, list, dictionary, nested, list-comprehension

I've tried to word this the best way that I possibly can, but it will probably be more clear if I provide an example of what I am trying to acheive:

Input:

```py
source_dictionary = {"person1": ["x1","x2","x3","x4"],
                     "person2": ["x1","x2","x3","x4"],
                     "person3": ["x1","x2"],
                     "person4": ["x1","x2"],
                     "person5": ["x1","x2"]
                    }
```

Intended output:

```
[["person1","person2"],["person3","person4","person5"]]
```

Handling the lists in the dictionary is proving to be quite a challenge.

Appologies, I forgot to include what I have tried so far. As mentioned above - I am having issues with the lists:

```py
rev_dict = {}
  
for key, value in source_dictionary.items():
    rev_dict.setdefault(value, set()).add(key)
      
result = [key for key, values in rev_dict.items()
                              if len(values) > 1]
```

Comment: You forgot to post how you attempted to solve this.

Comment: Group the dictionary items by the values: [https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby)

Comment: @wwii the potential drawback of `groupby` here is that you would need to sort by key (for a general case)

Comment: @mozway - sort by values?  your solution is better.

Comment: @wwii Yes by value!

Comment: Appologies for forgetting to include my previous attempts - I don't post much, and need to get used to Stack Overflow etiquette.  I have included these above, now. Thank you to everyone for evaluating and providing feedback, and proposing solutions

Comment: What should be the output if you exchange the positions of person 2 and 4?

Comment: @mozway Thanks for your contribution. I;ve included the full example, to make sure I understand the quesiton:

`source_dictionary = {"person1": ["x1","x2","x3","x4"],
                     "person4": ["x1","x2","x3","x4"],
                     "person3": ["x1","x2"],
                     "person2": ["x1","x2"],
                     "person5": ["x1","x2"]
                    }

target_list = [["person1","person4"],["person3","person2","person5"]]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you want to join the keys by identical value, use a [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict):

```py
source_dictionary = {"person1": ["x1","x2","x3","x4"],
                     "person2": ["x1","x2","x3","x4"],
                     "person3": ["x1","x2"],
                     "person4": ["x1","x2"],
                     "person5": ["x1","x2"]
                    }

from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(list)
for key, value in source_dictionary.items():
    d[tuple(value)].append(key)
    
out = list(d.values())
```

Alternative with `setdefault`:

```py
d = {}
for key, value in source_dictionary.items():
    d.setdefault(tuple(value), []).append(key)
    
out = list(d.values())
```

output:

```
[['person1', 'person2'], ['person3', 'person4', 'person5']]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
source_dictionary = {"person1": ["x1","x2","x3","x4"],
                     "person2": ["x1","x2","x3","x4"],
                     "person3": ["x1","x2"],
                     "person4": ["x1","x2"],
                     "person5": ["x1","x2"]
                    }

L = []
for i in source_dictionary.values():
    K = []
    for j in source_dictionary.keys():
        if source_dictionary[j] == i :
            K.append(j)
    if K not in L:
        L.append(K)

print(L)
```